# How can I add more glyphs in my True type font?

Tags: fontforge

I am creating my series of glyphs in a custom font but I can only see glyphs which occupy the character spaces from  U+0020 up until  U+007f when the font is read by other programs. Is there a setting to allow all other characters to be read? In my font all characters after  are called "control characters".

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

Glyphs which you add to your font appear based on the character that their encoding matches. If you add characters with no encoding, of course they won't be avaialble. You could consider giving them encodings of e.g. U+F000, U+F001, etc., which are in the Unicode [Private Use Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas). Then you could paste such characters into your program, or if you use Linux, some desktop environments allow you to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> and type e.g. `f000` and get the character U+F000.